# Fetch the updated call log and store it in a file

Tags: android, eclipse

i'm developing an android app that retrieves the call log and store it in a text file. I'm using the ContentObserver to observe for the changes and fetch the updated entry once there is a change. I'm able to fetch the entries correctly if i get a miss call, incoming call and make an outgoing call by dialing the number from the phone book. If i make an outgoing call by clicking the number from the call log, the onChange() method is called thrice. The onChange() is called once i select the name from the call log, before making a call, such that retrieving the previous event once. Once the call is made, the outgoing event is retrieved twice, totally making three entries. Please do suggest me a solution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In which URI did u register the observer. Is it android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI? If so then the onChange() method will be called only once.

Also, relying in content providers is not a good idea. Refer http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html. Instead of using content observers you can try using broadcast receiver with actions
android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE
android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL

Comment: I saw the link you mentioned. Yeah i tried using broadcast receiver before, when the phone comes to the IDLE state, i wrote the function that fetches the call log. But the problem i had here is, the IDLE state is called twice, making two entries. And if there is any solution for this, i want to use the broadcast receiver that listens to the phone state and once the phone state is IDLE, i want to start a service that fetches the call log. Any solution for this would be appreciated.